# Is it true that inductors filter current harmonics and Capacitors filter voltage harmonics in SMPS?

Tags: capacitor, inductor, power-electronics, passive-networks, harmonics

1. In switch mode power supply applications, it is true that **inductors** filter **current harmonics** and **Capacitors** filter **voltage harmonics**?
2. Is it true that in most applications we use LC filters due to the fact that we need to filter both the voltage and current harmonics?

Comment: 1. usually the main inductor has a different role. 2. close to accurate.

Comment: @dandavis
<<usually the main inductor has a different role>>

What is that role please?

Comment: A power supply of this type can have several inductors so please show an example circuit and refer to the inductor you are talking about. Mind reading isn't big on this site. Ditto telepathy. Insults can be funny though especially for the giver LOL.

Comment: it's a tank to store the back emf